# serial write pixels of a bmp image

Tags: string

I'm looking for a way to read a 24 bpp bmp file from a SD cart, and than convert it to text and write it to the serial monitor.

So the output should look something like this:
R255,B255,G255

And that for each pixel

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: SO, I have to skip the header somehow, and then read the pixels one by one. But how can you do that in the arduino IDE?

Comment: The worst thing with a BMP file is it's backwards. It starts at the bottom of the image not the top. Really annoying. You need first to read the header and get the right data out of it to then know how to get the image data.

Comment: And what if you know the data out of the header already, so it's always the same size and format. Can you begin with reading the pixels directly?

Comment: Sure, if you know the offset, ordering, and packing already. Just seek to the right location and start reading.

Comment: And what will be a command to Read the data in the arduino IDE?

Comment: The same one used in all the SD card reading examples.

Answer (score 2):

To read the pixels, start with this:

```
int32_t readNbytesInt(File *p_file, int position, byte nBytes)
{
    if (nBytes > 4)
        return 0;

    p_file->seek(position);

    int32_t weight = 1;
    int32_t result = 0;
    for (; nBytes; nBytes--)
    {
        result += weight * p_file->read();
        weight <<= 8;
    }
    return result
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);

    Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
    if (!SD.begin(53)) {
        Serial.println("initialization failed!");
        while (1); // <- this is how you should block execution, not with returns
    }
    Serial.println("initialization done.");


    // Open
    bmpImage = SD.open("Circle.bmp", FILE_READ);
    textFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);

    int32_t dataStartingOffset = readNbytesInt(&bmpImage, 0x0A, 4);

    // Change their types to int32_t (4byte)
    int32_t width = readNbytesInt(&bmpImage, 0x12, 4);
    int32_t height = readNbytesInt(&bmpImage, 0x16, 4);
    Serial.println(width);
    Serial.println(height);

    int16_t pixelsize = readNbytesInt(&bmpImage, 0x1C, 2);

    if (pixelsize != 24)
    {
        Serial.println("Image is not 24 bpp");
        while (1);
    }

    bmpImage.seek(dataStartingOffset);//skip bitmap header

    // 24bpp means you have three bytes per pixel, usually B G R

    byte R, G, B;

    for(int32_t i = 0; i < height; i ++) {
        for (int32_t j = 0; j < width; j ++) {
            B = bmpImage.read();
            G = bmpImage.read();
            R = bmpImage.read();
            textFile.print("R");
            textFile.print(R);
            textFile.print("G");
            textFile.print(G);
            textFile.print("B");
            textFile.print(B);
            textFile.print(" ");
        }
        textFile.print("\n");
    }

    bmpImage.close();
    textFile.close();

    Serial.println("done write");
}`
```

Source: [Arduino StackExchange Question: How to read bitmap image on arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19795/how-to-read-bitmap-image-on-arduino)

The text output of this should be a file with an array of strings like `R10G100B25`, where R is the red component of the pixel, G is the green component and B the blue one. Work out how to print these to the serial output.

Note this is only compatible with the 24bpp format.

Comment: If you feel this answers your question, you may want to "accept" the answer [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "command" to read BMP files. They're files like any other. If you know how to read files on an SD card with an Arduino, then you know how to read BMP files. *Interpreting* the bytes of the file you just read is another matter. If the details of the BMP (width, height, depth, array offset, etc.) are known already, you may *seek* to the pixel array directly and begin parsing it (in your case, 3 bytes at a time in BGR order), remembering that BMPs are typically arranged bottom-to-top unless the height field in the header is negative.